# Loading image texture onto a CVWindow

Tags: opengl, opencv

I'm working in OpenCV and have a window that I want to add an image texture to. My code so far:

```
void display(void) {  
    GLuint texture[1];
    IplImage *image;

    image=cvLoadImage("Particle.png");

    if(!image){
        std::cout << "image empty" << std::endl;
    } else {
        glGenTextures(1, texture);
        glBindTexture(1,  GL_TEXTURE_2D );

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        // Set texture clamping method
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    }

    cvReleaseImage(&image);
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    display();
}

//window to draw the texture on
cvNamedWindow("video");
```

I'm new to OpenGL and find it confusing so any tips on how to improve it would be great or where to go from here (how to draw it on the window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, you don't need to do any work in OpenGL to draw an image in a window: OpenCV provides this functionality already with the function [`cvShowImage()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?#imshow).

Code to show the window might then be:

```
if(!image)
{
    std::cout << "image empty" << std::endl;
}
else
{
    cvNamedWindow("image");      // Create the window
    cvShowImage("image", image); // Display image in the window
    cvWaitKey();                 // Display window until a key is pressed
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! for some reason the window isn't showing up but at least the error is gone, probably now my image for some reason doesn't exist.

Comment: @AndreaF I suspect the window is shown and disappears very quickly. Adding `cvWaitKey()` will keep the window open until you press a key (see my edit). If my answer helped, would you accept it? Also, if you can, you should use the C++ API instead of the C API.

Comment: Still have an empty image but will figure that out and then should work. I would switch over but I haven't worked much cv::mat and because I'm doing colour tracking, wasn't sure if I could use C++ as easily as it is in C. At least the colour tracking tutorials seemed to be in C.

Comment: The C++ API is (much) easier to use than the C API. The only catch would be if you aren't already familiar with C++. But I would recommend switching, especially if you are just starting out.